# Unable to add action listener in gridbaglayout

Tags: java, actionlistener, gridbaglayout

This is my code how can I add action listener I already tried methods I known but due to static methods I am unable to add it.Netbeans IDE suggested the action listener in the program but I am not able to use it can someone suggest a more simple method to declare the action listener.

public class Calc {

```
public static void addComponentsToPane(Container pane) {


        pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gBC = new GridBagConstraints();

        gBC.ipady = 40;
        gBC.ipadx = 40;

        JTextField JTextField = new JTextField("Hello");
        gBC.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gBC.gridx = 0;
        gBC.gridy = 0;
        gBC.gridwidth = 4;
        JTextField.setEditable(false);
        pane.add(JTextField, gBC);

        //JButton jbnButton;
        gBC.gridwidth = 1;

        JButton b7 = new JButton("7");
        gBC.gridx = 0;
        gBC.gridy = 1;
        pane.add(b7, gBC);
        // more calculator buttons declared here
```

//Here how it suggest the actionlistner

```
        b0.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            b0ActionPerformed(evt);
        }

        private void b0ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)  }
        `
    });
    b0.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        b0ActionPerformed(evt);
    }
    private void b0ActionPerformed(Actionenter Event evt) {}
    });}

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
```

}

Comment: Welcome on SO. Consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Om which component do you want to add an actionListener. And what have you tried so far?

Comment: want to add listener anywhere in the code where my calculator button performs the desired operation. when clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try this for you. You can add action listener in addComponentsToPane method for every component you declare. Also, you forgot to pass the frame so you can pass it in the main method as I do.

```
public class Calc {

public static void addComponentsToPane(Container pane) {

    pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gBC = new GridBagConstraints();

    gBC.ipady = 40;
    gBC.ipadx = 40;

    JTextField JTextField = new JTextField("Hello");
    gBC.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gBC.gridx = 0;
    gBC.gridy = 0;
    gBC.gridwidth = 4;
    JTextField.setEditable(false);
    pane.add(JTextField, gBC);

    //JButton jbnButton;
    gBC.gridwidth = 1;

    JButton b7 = new JButton("7");
    gBC.gridx = 0;
    gBC.gridy = 1;
    pane.add(b7, gBC);
    // more calculator buttons declared here

    b7.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // Write your action here

        }
    });

}

private static void createAndShowGUI(JFrame pane) {
    addComponentsToPane(pane);
    pane.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI(new JFrame());
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks it worked. I was getting the problem because I always do GUI programming through NetBeans design tab.